# How can I adjust the content in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help from you guys. I have a excel file. In the file, in few columns, data star from column d and, in few coulumns it start from column E. But all the data should be started from column D. I have more than 100 files. If I manually make changes in all the files, it will make more than 7 days.

Is there any formula to adjust the content?

[image: Data example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It won't take 7 days - just a few keystrokes are needed for this operation.*

Select the entire column D

On the Home tab, in the Editing group, click Find & Select > Go to Special. Or press F5 and click Special… . In the Go To Special dialog box, select Blanks and click OK. This will select all empty cells in the range.

Now choose Delete-Delete Cells or press Ctrl+Minus. In the window that appears, select **Delete with a shift to the left**.

Make sure the result matches your expectations.

Now you can record this sequence of actions in a macro and execute it with a single hotkey press.